# Timer causing app to freeze in some situations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction) startRecognition:(id)sender {
    backgroundSoundLevel = [backgroundSoundChange stringValue];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{   
    NSString *charlieSoundVolume = [charlieSoundLevel stringValue];
    if ([charlieSoundVolume isLessThan: backgroundSoundLevel]) {
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"", charlieSoundVolume, @"", @"", @"");
    }
}
```

So when you press the button "startRecognition" then it starts this timer loop "timer fired". BUT when the value charlieSoundVolume is less than backgroundSoundLevel, it freezes the app. When it's greater, it works fine. So there's something wrong with that part of the code. I'm not really sure what...

Background info: charlieSoundVolume is the current volume expressed in an NSString. backgroundSoundVolume is also expressed in an NSString. The charlieSoundVolume is the current volume and the backgroundSoundVolume is the preset volume set by the NSSlider backGroundSoundChange.

Any ideas??

Elijah

Comment: When you say "freezes the app," you mean the panel doesn't show up and the app stops responding or what?

Comment: Yes, the panel does not show up, I get a rainbow spinning thing and the app stops responding. What do you mean? I use this to say if one NSString is less than the other NSString.

Comment: I fixed your title and tags. Please choose more descriptive titles and more appropriate tags in the future.

(Also, consider a user name that doesn't impersonate anyone. Anonymity is fine, impersonation isn't.)

Comment: Ok, Thanks! But that's my actual name...I know it's the same as the actors, but I can't really do much about that :D

Comment: Comment out your `NSRunAlertPanel` and put something else. You said yourself that is the problem. Start there.

Comment: That's not the issue. I took it out, still freezes the app.

Comment: Elijah Wood: You shouldn't treat strings as numbers, particularly for numeric comparison. “100” is less than “50”. Get the strings' `double` values and compare them using C's less-than operator.

Comment: Can you post an example as an answer?

Comment: Elijah Wood: If your app is frozen, sample it, using either Activity Monitor (same tool users use) or Instruments. That will tell you what it is doing. You need to know what it's doing to know how to make it stop doing that.

Comment: Elijah Wood: As a rule, I do not write examples—it is *your* task to write the code; mine as the answerer is to tell you what you need to (or should and should not) write. You need to ask the NSString objects for their `double` values, and compare those values using C's less-than operator. You can look the first part up in the documentation (see Xcode's Help menu), and you should know the second part already, since you need to know at least basic C to use Cocoa effectively. If you don't, I suggest this book: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596804794/

Comment: I GOT IT!!! I'm posting the correct code as the answer.

Comment: Elijah - my apologies, I've seen plenty of people elsewhere online do that. I'll edit my comment if I can.

Comment: Oh, no problem! I know what you mean! :D and btw, thanks SOOO much for your help. You've responded very quickly and your answers will guide me through objective-c better. I WILL BE A GENIUS! :D Thanks again! Elijah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
- (IBAction) startRecognition:(id)sender {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{   
    backgroundSoundLevel = [backgroundSoundChange stringValue];
    NSString *charlieSoundVolume = [charlieSoundLevel stringValue];
    if ([charlieSoundVolume  isLessThan: backgroundSoundLevel]) {
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"", charlieSoundVolume, @"", @"", @"");
    }
}
```

Comment: So `backgroundSoundLevel` is a string, but `charlieSoundLevel` is a control? You need to name your variables more clearly. (And stop storing data in controls! Your controller object should own one or both of these value objects directly.)

Comment: Yes. backgroundSoundLevel is the value that the NSSlider produces. charlieSoundLevel is the value of an NSTextField (which a quartz composer view changes with a patch, this quartz composer view file is a visualizer template that just gets the sound level). A little confusing, but the WHOLE app works now PERFECTLY! So, I'll look through it and make it more efficient. :D

Comment: According to the code in your answer, `charlieSoundLevel` is not the value of an NSTextField, but a control (possibly a text field) itself.